# Global 301 redirection from domain to www.domain

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, http-status-code-301, global-asax

could i use the begin request of Global.asax to redirect everything,

from *mydomain.domain* to *www.mydomain.domain*?

If this one is true, how can i do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string currentUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path.ToLower();
  if(currentUrl.StartsWith("http://mydomain"))
  {
    Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
    Response.AddHeader("Location", currentUrl.Replace("http://mydomain", "http://www.mydomain"));
    Response.End();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, i found that the PreRequest handler did not exist in the global.asax so i added it as you proposed. But the event is not fired in debug mode... I am doing something else wrong here?

Comment: Is it firing when you change `PreRequestHandlerExecute` into `BeginRequest`?

Comment: Yeap! The BeginRequest fires in every request

Comment: Then move the inner piece to BeginRequest and you'd be fine.

Comment: Request.Path only returns the virtual path, without the domain name.  The above code will not work.

Comment: this caused an error 302, temporary moved. since this post is 6 years old, things may have changed

Answer (score 11):

A couple of minor changes to Jan's answer got it working for me:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string currentUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower(); 
    if (currentUrl.StartsWith("http://mydomain"))
    {
        Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
        Response.AddHeader("Location", currentUrl.Replace("http://mydomain", "http://www.mydomain"));
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Changes were to use the BeginRequest event and to set currentUrl to HttpContext.Current.Request.Url instead of HttpContext.Current.Request.Path.  See:

http://www.mycsharpcorner.com/Post.aspx?postID=40

Comment: Does BeginRequest occur before or after PreRequestHandlerExecute?